# ERROR 1064 (42000) in Create table statement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, create-table

The below `create table` statement is giving an error but everything seams OK.

```
 explain create table inventory(`id` int primary key, 
         name varchar(30), price float, category varchar(25));
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create table inventory(`id` int primary key, name varchar(30), price float, cate' at line 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`explain`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) is used to get an execution plan of a `select` query (or the structure of an existing table, although it's more common to use `describe` for that). You cannot apply it to a `create table` statement. Just remove the `explain` keyword and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Read manual [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) and  [EXPLAIN Output Format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html)

When you precede a `SELECT` statement with the keyword `EXPLAIN`, MySQL displays information from the optimizer about the statement execution plan. That is, MySQL explains how it would process the statement, including information about how tables are joined and in which order. For information about using `EXPLAIN` to obtain execution plan information,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
create table inventory(`id` int primary key, 
name varchar(30), price float, category varchar(25));
```